# Passing data from one fucntion to another. Python

Tags: python, pyqt, event-handling, pyqt5, desktop-application

I am working on an app and I have made a UI with the qt5 creator. I have a function bound to a button.

```
self.dataChooseBtn.clicked.connect(self.selectFile)
self.data_processing.clicked.connect(self.process)

def selectFile(self):    
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выберите стандартизированную выборку", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        print(fileName)
        return fileName
```

When pressing this button, I get a dialog window, where I can choose a file.

Also, I have a function, that should process the chosen file. Right now, the path to file and its name are hardcoded.

```
def process(self):
    file_location = "/Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science\ comput/Application/Sheet.xlsx"
    sample = pd.read_excel('Sheet.xlsx', sheetname ='Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

What I want, is to get the output of a `selectFile()` function (triggered by the click) 
(for example: /Users/Graygood/Desktop/Science comput/Application/Sheet.xlsx)
 and insert it into `process()` function (also triggered by the click), without triggering the dialog window again. Which happens if I just call `selectFile()` function in `process()` one.

```
def process(self):
    fileName = self.selectFile()
    file_location = fileName
    sample = pd.read_excel('Sheet.xlsx', sheetname ='Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

Comment: have you tried `def process(self, file_name): ...` and calling it from the method `selectFile` instead of print just do `process(fileName)`

Comment: Do you have several fileName in same time or just one to store ?

Comment: Why not pass the name of the file to the `process` function defining `def process(self, filename)`

Comment: @Yohboy only one to store

Comment: So why don't you use fileName as a class attribute ? you can use self.fileName to store the fileName and so don't need to pass it in function.

Comment: @Yohboy the problem is that I am not that good at python, so I don't know how/where to use self.fileName in order to work correctly. atm I made smth like this, but when I ask to print me "file" it returns False.
`def process(self, fileName):
        file = fileName
        print(file)
        sample = pd.read_excel(file)`

Comment: I added an answer does it help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use fileName as  a class attribute and so store your filename to be able to keep track if you want to reuse it without passing it in all your function.

Just need to change `selectFile` to:

```
def selectFile(self):    
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выберите стандартизированную выборку", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        print(fileName)
        self.fileName = fileName
```

and then call `self.fileName` in `process(self)`.

To avoid error, you should also declare it in **init** method : `self.fileName = None`  and always test if `self.fileName` exists before trying to use it.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is get the open file path on button click. And call the process method on the file_path

```
def selectFile(self):    
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    # read the file path
    file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выберите стандартизированную выборку", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
    if file_path:
        # print the file_path and call process on it.
        print(file_path)
        self.process(file_path)
        return file_path

def process(self, file_path):
    # read the file at path and process it
    sample = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname ='Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
    print("processed")
```